# Random walk on Markov Chain Transition matrix

Tags: python, markov-chains

I have a cumulative transition matrix and need to build a simple random walk algorithm to generate let's say 500 values from the matrix as efficiently as possible (the actual matrix is 1000 x 1000)

```
cum_sum

[array([0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9, 1. ]),
array([0.5 , 0.5 , 0.5 , 0.75, 1.  ]),
array([0.66666667, 1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        ]),
array([0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1. , 1. ]),
array([0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1. , 1. ])]
```

1. Select the initial state *i* in the matrix randomly
2. Produce a random value between 0 and 1
3. The value of the random number is compared with the elements of the *i*-th row of the cumulative matrix. If the random number value was greater then the cumulative probability of the previous state but less than or equal to the cumulative probability of the following state the followin state is adopted.

Something I tried

```
def random_walk(cum_sum):
start_point=random.choice([item[0] for item in cum_sum])
random=np.random.uniform(0,1,1)
if random > start_point:
```

Comment: What happened? it seems you "unaccepted" the answer? any special reason for that?

Answer (score 3):

You can use numpy random [choice](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) at each stage to simulate a transition.

You can give the probability as the argument `p`, and the first positional argument define the sample space. In order to convert the cumulative probability distribution to a probability distribution what I do is to insert a zero at the beginning and use numpy diff to compute the increase at each step.

Preparing your example probabilities

```py
P = np.array([
    [0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9, 1. ],
    [0.5 , 0.5 , 0.5 , 0.75, 1.  ],
    [0.66666667, 1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        ],
    [0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1. , 1. ],
    [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1. , 1. ]])
P = np.diff(np.hstack([np.zeros((len(P), 1)), P]), axis=1)
```

Then run a few steps

```py
i = 0;
path = [0]
I = np.arange(len(P))
for _ in range(10):
    i = np.random.choice(I, p = P[i])
    path.append(i);
print(path)
```